# Having trouble reading a YUV video with mplayer/mencoder

Tags: video, mplayer, mencoder, mjpeg, yuv

I'm making some experiences with the YUV raw video format. This YUV video I created (with ppmtoy4m from mjpegtools, from a series of screenshots taken at 24 fps) plays OK with Totem, correct rate, correct colors, everything. Plus, ffmpeg can convert it to a .mpg just fine. But mplayer and mencoder get lost. I'm using version 1.0-0.47.svn20100703 in CentOS 6.

I tried...

```
mplayer video.yuv -demuxer rawvideo -rawvideo w=1152:h=864:format=i420
```

...but the result is a weird frame displacement like an old TV with a deregulated horizontal. Seemingly, it's interpreting the frame headers as if they were part of the frame.

The bzipped YUV file can be found [here](http://users.vialink.com.br/jcastro/video.yuv.bz2) (WARNING: 34 megs compressed, 3.5 gigs uncompressed!)

The indiviual ppm frames are [here](http://users.vialink.com.br/jcastro/frames.tar.bz2) (2.8 megs compressed, 557 megs uncompressed)

The video was generated with

```
cat *.ppm | ppmtoy4m -F 24:1 >video.yuv
```

Is there a parameter I'm missing?

Comment: YUV files have no frame header, so that's not the issue. I suspect the culprit is the fact that you're using a really old version of mplayer that might just have a bug. Will try to check the file later.

Comment: Two years on, did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem, I can get around the horizontal scrolling by manually setting the frame size to (x*y*1.5)+6  (to soak up the "FRAME\n" at the end of each frame), but there is still a bit of an offset because of the YUV4MPEG header at the beginning of the file. I read elsewhere that mplayer should be able to play a YUV4MPEG stream simply with "mplayer stream.yuv" but that produces a lot of "Frame too small!" messages.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that y4m format is not yuv.  As slhck mentioned yuv has NO metadata and lacks even width and height information (not to mention specifying 4:2:0 4:2:2 or 4:4:4 ; 8-bit, 10-bit, 16-bit variants).

I found a description of Y4M format at https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=YUV4MPEG2 and it definitely has metadata.

If you want raw yuv streams that `mplayer` can play, `ppmtoy4m` will not generate those.  You might be able to use

```
ffmpeg -i %04d.ppm -c:v rawvideo -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p video.yuv
```

If instead you want to play a y4m stream, someone else will have to dig up the correct arguments to `mplayer` (or another tool).